# assigning letters numbers values from the field

Tags: python

assigned letter number

I have this program that is used to assign numbers to letters.

I have a problem with two letters. the program returns the value instead of letters.

But I have a problem with multiple letters.

For example, if I have 1 letter with the input: `ABC`, the output is: `[1,2,3]`. This works fine, but I have a problem with more letters, what am I doing wrong?

When there are more letters, two letters are checked first:

```
ABC

ACB

BAC

BCA

CAB

CBA
```

all permutations and pismenum were given value.

ABC should have several results so that the number of the first two letters is counted and then the last one as well. `alphabet` and `alphabet1` should be used for this.

if I had input `ABC` output I would expect:

```
AB C

AC B

BA C

BC A

CB A
```

and each output will have a number of letters with premutation therefore `ABC = 2.3`, `BAC = 2.3` and duplicates can be deleted.

```
AB C = [2,3] AB = 2 and C = 3

A C B = [1,3,2]

BA C = [2,3]

BC A = [4,1]

CB A = [4,1]
```

they only need two numbers, the duplicates delay the next part of the program()

```
BA C = [2,3]

AB C = [2,3] #this is duplicates number () in a different order



BC A = [4,1]

CB A = [4,1] #same duplicates
```

The output I want is this:

```
AB C = [2,3] 

BC A = [4,1]
```

however, there will also be more double letters, for example `ABCD`, and between these I want to permute again and assign numbers to the letters / if they are found in double letters, then look for all the remaining ones in the normal alphabet

IF ABAB output is `[2,2]`

if ABABA output is `[2,2,1]`

```
    import itertools
    
    alphabet = {
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2,
        "C": 3,
        "D": 4,
        "E": 5,
        "F": 6,
        "G": 7,
        "H": 8,
        "I": 9,
        "J": 10,
        "K": 11,
        "L": 12,
        "M": 13,
        "N": 14,
        "O": 15,
        "P": 16,
        "Q": 17,
        "R": 18,
        "S": 19,
        "T": 20,
        "U": 21,
        "V": 22,
        "W": 23,
        "X": 24,
        "Y": 25,
        "Z": 26,
        "": 0
    }
    
    alphabet1 = {
        "AA": 1,
        "AB": 2,
        "BB": 3,
        "BC": 4,
        "CC": 5,
        "CD": 6,
        "DD": 7,
        "DE": 8,
        "EE": 9,
        "EF": 10,
        "FF": 11,
        "FG": 12,
        "GG": 13,
        "GH": 14,
        "HH": 15,
        "HI": 16,
        "II": 17,
        "IJ": 18,
        "JJ": 19,
        "JK": 20,
        "KK": 21,
        "KL": 22,
        "LL": 23,
        "LM": 24,
        "MM": 25,
        "MN": 26,
        "NN": 27,
        "NO": 28,
        "OO": 29,
        "OP": 30,
        "PP": 31,
        "PQ": 32,
        "QQ": 33,
        "QR": 34,
        "RR": 35,
        "RS": 36,
        "SS": 37,
        "ST": 38,
        "TT": 39,
        "TU": 40,
        "UU": 41,
        "UV": 42,
        "VV": 43,
        "VW": 44,
        "WW": 45,
        "WX": 46,
        "XX": 47,
        "XY": 48,
        "YY": 49,
        "YZ": 50,
        "ZZ": 51
    }
      
def gen_combination_values(n):
    comb_values = {}
    for i in range(n + 1):
        for product in itertools.product(alphabet.keys(), repeat=i):
            prod = list(product)
            prod.sort()
            value = 0
            comb = ""
            for char in product:
                value += alphabet[char]
                comb += char
            try:
                comb_values[value].add(comb)
            except KeyError:
                comb_values[value] = set()
                comb_values[value].add(comb)
    print(comb_values)
    return comb_values


def gematria(word):
    result = 0
    for char in word:
        result += alphabet[char]
    return result


def combinations_w(word):
    """returns all possible word with replacement by each letter value """
    letters_values = []
    for c in word:
        print(c)
        letters_values.append(alphabet[c])
    word_poss = []
    for l_value in letters_values:
        word_poss.append(list(values[l_value]))
    poss = []
    for i in set(itertools.product(*word_poss)):
        poss.append("".join(i))
    return poss


if __name__ == '__main__':
    values = gen_combination_values(1)
    for i in combinations_w("JE"):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Please have a look again at your question if it is still correct after my edits. The format was really bad.

Comment: `NameError: name 'values' is not defined`. What is `values`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import itertools

alphabet = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4}
alphabet1 = {"AA": 1,"AB": 2, "BB": 3, "BC": 4}

def word_permutations(word):
    '''Returns all word permutations'''
    return [''.join(letters) for letters in itertools.permutations(word)]

def extract_one_number_from_word(word):
    '''Extract one number and return the rest of the word'''
    if len(word) >= 2:
        double = word[:2]
        if double in alphabet1:
            return alphabet1[double], word[2:]
        double = double[1] + double[0] # reverse letter order
        if double in alphabet1:
            return alphabet1[double], word[2:]
    first_letter = word[0]
    return alphabet[first_letter], word[1:]

def word_to_numbers(word):
    '''Convert word to numbers'''
    numbers = []
    while len(word) > 0:
        number, word = extract_one_number_from_word(word)
        numbers.append(number)
    return numbers

def combinations_w(word):
    """returns all possible word with replacement by each letter value """
    words = word_permutations(word)
    combinations = set()
    for word in words:
        word_numbers = word_to_numbers(word)
        combinations.add(tuple(word_numbers)) # set doesn't work with lists
    return [list(number_combination) for number_combination in combinations]

print(word_permutations('ABB'))
# ['ABB', 'ABB', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'BAB', 'BBA']

print(extract_one_number_from_word('ABB'))
# (2, 'B')
print(extract_one_number_from_word('ACB'))
# (1, 'CB')
    
print(word_to_numbers('ACB'))
# [1, 4]

print(combinations_w('AA'))
# [[1]]
print(combinations_w('ABC'))
# [[2, 3], [3, 2], [4, 1], [1, 4]]
```

Comment: Your word is "ABCD", not "ABBC". Is it a mistake?

Comment: "ABCD" => "ADBC". "A": 1, "D": 4, "BC": 4. [1, 4, 4]

Comment: How did you get "ABBC" from "ABCD"?

Comment: Can combinations_w('ABCD') produce "ABBC" and "ABBA" and "ABBAA"?

Comment: I understood that only permutations are used. Could you clarify it?

Comment: Do you mean permutations with returning?

Comment: your code works fine, i probably made a mistake with the answer thanx for help and you time I still choose to remove duplicates in permutations

[[2, 100],[100, 2]]

I'll do that myself, thank you, and my goal was to choose the lowest possible number of letters

which your code meets as long as I add filtering

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to give you a solution code, because this looks like homework.

You need to handle the case where there are more than one letter to be transformed. A simple way of doing this is to check if the string has a length longer than 1. If it does, take the first two letters out and translate them to a number. Repeat with the rest of the string, until there is 0 or 1 letter left, in which case you stop, or translate the one letter, respectively.

I want to add that your alphabet1 map does not have close to all the permutations possible with two letters. There would be 676 permutations of 2 letters. So you should probably find a way to generate that map programmatically, instead of listing it. If you want to handle all cases at least.

In the future, try to ask more direct questions that can be answered on Stackoverflow.

Comment: bro, they really need help with this, I'm new to programming and I don't know how to do it, that's why I asked for help, thank you for your answer

Comment: I have a code that I did but it doesn't work properly completely failed if have ABCD and leters lphabeth is AC an BC he won't find them in the permutation

Comment: `from itertools import product
leters = (list(product(iter('ABCZ'), repeat=2)))`but I really don't know how to do it and they need advice or help the best

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show you my solution:

```
from collections import Counter

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signle_letter_counter = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0, "E": 0}  # I'm stopping at E for short, you should add here the rest of the letters
    alphabet = {"AB": 10, "A": 1, "B": 2, "BC": 1001, "C": 3, "CD": 1002, "D": 4, "DE": 4, "E": 5, "": 0}
    s = "ABBA"
    output = []
    single_letter_list = list(signle_letter_counter.keys())
    single_letter_list.sort()
    counter = Counter(s)
    for key in single_letter_list:
        signle_letter_counter[key] = counter[key]
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i+1 < len(single_letter_list):
            if single_letter_list[i] + single_letter_list[i+1] in list(alphabet.keys()):
                pairs = min(signle_letter_counter[single_letter_list[i]], signle_letter_counter[single_letter_list[i+1]])
                for j in range(pairs):
                    output.append(alphabet[single_letter_list[i] + single_letter_list[i+1]])
                exeeding_letter_index = None
                if signle_letter_counter[single_letter_list[i]] > signle_letter_counter[single_letter_list[i+1]]:
                    exeeding_letter_index = i
                if signle_letter_counter[single_letter_list[i+1]] > signle_letter_counter[single_letter_list[i]]:
                    exeeding_letter_index = i+1
                if exeeding_letter_index is not None:
                    for j in range(abs(signle_letter_counter[single_letter_list[i]] - signle_letter_counter[single_letter_list[i+1]])):
                        output.append(alphabet[single_letter_list[exeeding_letter_index]])
                i += 2
            else:
                for g in range(signle_letter_counter[single_letter_list[i]]):
                    output.append(alphabet[single_letter_list[i]])
                i += 1
        else:
            break
    print(output)
```

Result:

```
[10, 10]
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work at 100% if I have `s = "ABBA"` the result should only be `10.10`

Comment: written where there is only one only if it is not in many `ABBA = 10.10 ABBAA = 10,10,1 ` the last 1 is the last letter that did not have a pair

Comment: @HonzaAlt can you check if there are other cases where it doesn't work as you expect? (I've updated the code!!)

Comment: the previous question is correct, thank you for your time       `s = "ABBABC" give [10, 10, 2, 3] and no  [10, 10, 1001]

Comment: so it's not correct :D I checked it and there are more combinations for individual words and for more